# Why does the Decimal python module give me 4 digits after the decimal point even though i set the precision to 2?

Tags: python, decimal

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 2

a = Decimal("0.8727")
print(a)
```

**Output:** 0.8727

I dont understand why the output is not 0.87

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get 0.87

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal("0.8727").quantize(Decimal('1.00'),rounding="ROUND_DOWN")
```